# Laptop config with GPU for Mobile Linux Computer Vision?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, linux

I'm looking to buy a laptop for use in many mobile CV projects, mostly using OpenCV. Namely some involving stereo vision and others involving object or location detection. I really prefer working in Linux, not looking for a config that will only work with Windows.

That being said, I'm a bit disconnected from the latest and greatest computer hardware these days, being mostly involved in public cloud computing for the past few years. I'm looking for recommendations from low end to high end so I can compare and contrast for what I need long term. It would be nice to just pick up a laptop from newegg or amazon that has all that I need, but not averse to building something either. I'd also prefer lightweight, but no problem if the power sacrifice is too great here. (If you haven't guessed from my indecisiveness, just looking for any and all suggestions :) ).